# User does not respond to ‘devise’ method during runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, runtime-error

While running rails server, I would get this error once in a while after I run into temporary errors in my code during development.

```
[INFO] Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1
[FATAL]
RuntimeError (User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'):
  config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  config/initializers/logger_config.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

After which, the server will become useless and lose all my routes.

```
[INFO] Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1
[FATAL]
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/cancel"):
  config/initializers/logger_config.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Does anyone have a fix for this? Its pretty frustrating for a developer to keep restarting the server every time this happens and the other solutions are to solve for the initialization of devise.

This is still plaguing me every time I edit certain ajax fetches that seems to be cached.

Comment: Just a side note: I do call `devise_for :users, :controllers => {...}` at config/routes.rb:6 to override some devise controller functionality.

Comment: "Does anyone have a fix for this? " - the error message has instructions built-in. Have you followed them?

Comment: Yes. In both devise.rb and application.rb, I have require 'devise/orm/active_record' in them. This is more likely a cache problem because whenever I do code changes that call for activerecord where, the invalidation of the cache causes it to lose the link to the user table. I do need to investigate more as this possibly might have nothing to do with devise.